# MomentJS with react languages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm using moment JS with React and I have a problem with changing language. When I type `moment.lang('pl')` or `moment.locale('pl')` and then `moment.format('MMMM')` it only shows month in english. Is there any way to fix it?

**Code**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';


class Time extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


        this.state = {}
    }


    render() {

        let march = moment();

        moment.lang('pl');

        console.log(march.format('MMMM'));

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="time">
                    <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Time;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you set the languege after you get the time.

To fix it just swap the line like this :

```
import 'moment/locale/pl'// add this line below your moment import

moment.lang('pl');
let march = moment();
```

Also this is an example that I try before answer you.

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/pl'

let a = moment();

moment.locale('pl')
let b = moment();

console.log(a.format('MMMM')); //July
console.log(b.format('MMMM')); //lipiec
```

Actually, `moment.lang` **is deprecated after version 2.8.0** (For Yarn or NPM this seems to deprecated since 2.10 that i tried). If you use later version, please use `moment.locale` instead.

more information here : http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/

Comment: It still shows me July in console log but it also shows me an error `moment.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` I am on moment.js in version 2.18

Comment: @KonradUciechowski Then you're not transpiling w/ anything that recognizes JSX.

Comment: @KonradUciechowski check you jsx transpiler like webpack or something else.

Comment: @Natsathorn I don't know what is wrong with my app but in my case I just copy paste your solution and in my case it shows "July" two times instead of "July" "Lipiec"

Comment: @Natsathorn also I created simple html and test your solution on just simple html, It still shows me "July" two times instead of "July" "Lipiec"

Comment: @KonradUciechowski ok let me have a look

Comment: @KonradUciechowski please delete my example code from your question. It would confused someone read after.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to Natsathorn's answer, you can import it dynamically with

```
import(`moment/locale/${navigator.language.toLocaleLowerCase()}`).then();
```